# It is div:$\mathbb{P}_k\rightarrow \mathbb{P}_{k-1}$ surjective?

Tags: polynomials

My question is:

It is the operator

$\text{div}:\;(\mathbb{P}_k){\color{red}{^3}}\rightarrow (\mathbb{P}_{k-1})$ surjective ?

Here $\mathbb{P}_k$ denotes, as usual, the set of polynomial with degree equal or less than $k$, and div is the divergence operator.

Thanks!

Comment: What's div here? I don't see why there would be a natural "divergence" on $\mathbb{P}_k$.

Comment: Thanks Ian, I added a red "3". Div is the usual divergence operatos.

Comment: Shouldn't the usual divergence operator map $(P_k)^3$ to $P_{k-1}$, not $(P_{k-1})^3$?

Comment: of course Micah (thanks for noted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the answer is yes. Let $p = a_0 + a_1 x + \dots + a_{k-1} x^{k-1} \in \mathbb{P}_{k-1}$. Then one of its preimages in $(\mathbb{P}_k)^3$ under $\text{div}$ is

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a_0 x_1 + a_1 x_1^2/2 + a_2 x_1^3/3 + \dots + a_k x_1^k/k \\
0 \\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: jinx :).   Took too long figuring out all the syntax

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if we're talking about real/complex/rational field as your field of the polynomials Let $\sum _{j=0}^{k-1}a_jx^j$ be your polynomial in your range,  then a preimage will be generated by $(\sum _{j=0}^{k-1}(a_{j}/(j+1))\cdot x^{j+1},1,1)$